# Pivot Table in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Can I use pivot function  with this data? I tried max aggregation it seems that it picks up the maximum value only. Here's my query, anyone can polish it?

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/5UMZoLC9

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT '2020' IDN, 'ENGLISH' SUBJECT, 'E101' ITEM UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020' IDN, 'ENGLISH' SUBJECT, 'E102' ITEM UNION ALL
    SELECT '2020' IDN, 'MATH' SUBJECT, 'M101' ITEM UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021' IDN, 'ENGLISH' SUBJECT, 'E101' ITEM UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021' IDN, 'ENGLISH' SUBJECT, 'E102' ITEM UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021' IDN, 'ENGLISH' SUBJECT, 'E103' ITEM
  ) AA
) BB
PIVOT
(
  MAX([ITEM]) FOR [SUBJECT] IN ([ENGLISH], [MATH])
) AS PVT`
```

Table:

```
IDN SUBJECT ITEM
2020    ENGLISH E101
2020    ENGLISH E102
2020    MATH    M101
2021    ENGLISH E101
2021    ENGLISH E102
2021    ENGLISH E103
```

Desired Result:

```
IDN ENGLISH MATH
2020    E101    M101
2020    E102    NULL
2021    E101    NULL
2021    E102    NULL
2021    E103    NULL
```

Comment: In the middle level, add `SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDN, SUBJECT ORDER BY ITEM)`

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to align the items into rows via a shared value, this can be achived by using `row_number()` and then in the group by clause use that in addition to the iIDN

```
SELECT IDN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'ENGLISH' THEN ITEM END) as ENGLISH,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SUBJECT = 'MATH' THEN ITEM END) as MATH
FROM (
     SELECT IDN, SUBJECT, ITEM,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDN, SUBJECT ORDER BY ITEM) as rn
     FROM raw
     ) t
GROUP BY IDN, rn
```

| IDN | ENGLISH | MATH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | E101 | M101 |
| 2021 | E101 | *null* |
| 2020 | E102 | *null* |
| 2021 | E102 | *null* |
| 2021 | E103 | *null* |

OR, using the pivot operator:

```
SELECT IDN,
       [ENGLISH],
       [MATH]
FROM (
  SELECT IDN, SUBJECT, ITEM,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDN, SUBJECT ORDER BY ITEM) as rn
  FROM raw
) t
PIVOT (
  MAX(ITEM)
  FOR SUBJECT IN ([ENGLISH], [MATH])
) p
ORDER BY IDN, [ENGLISH]
```

See SQL Server [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wToUqIsj)